# If a Person’s Intent Is Good but the Outcome Is Negative, Is Their Action Ethical in the Framework of Deontology?

Tags: deontology

I am unsure about how this question would be classified within the framework of Deontology, and have been unable to find a answer that resolves my question.

For example:

> Let's say that a person makes a post to social media spreading
> information about something they believe is a huge problem. As a
> result, that post goes viral and other people commit acts of violence
> against a group of people in response to learning about this
> information.

If the original intent behind posting was good but the outcome that resulted was bad, would this be considered unethical?

Comment: Generally, from the perspective of *universal principles*, or stage six in [Kohlberg's stages of moral development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Kohlberg's_stages_of_moral_development), the principles themselves are held above the outcome. If a particular principle were found problematic over time, the principle may be changed; but the people following the principle would generally not be seen as immoral.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that some forms of consequentialism would consider the poster in the example you gave as acting morally despite the negative consequences of his acts. These forms argue that an action is moral or immoral based on what the agent *expected* to happen, not what actually happened. (https://iep.utm.edu/consequentialism-utilitarianism/#SH1d). The SEP called this position subjective consequentialism (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deontological thought is generally defined as an ethical system in which ethical actions are those that follow principles, rules, or guidelines *as opposed to* a system in which ethical action is defined as action that has a desirable (in whatever form that may take) consequence.

In other words, under most deontological systems, an action is not judged according to its consequences at all! Only according to the intention of the agent can the morality of an action be judged.

If the person in your example genuinely believed that they are following a reasonable moral rule, then according to most forms of deontology they are not culpable for whatever consequences follow.

Comment: I feel like this is a really good answer to my question, but could probably be helped with referencing to the deontological systems that would classify this as ethical.

Comment: It is hard to classify the example since there is very little detail, but the SEP article on deontology (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-deontological/) is a good place to review what different philosophers believe.

Comment: I think I'm in disagreement with this idea that principles and rules correspond to principles of intention.  One can defend a position of deontological moral realism - that there are rules that ought to be followed independently of what the person involved believes, and to be moral is to follow **those** rules, rather than simply to follow one's own moral compass.

Comment: For this kind of deontological perspective, the moral question isn't whether the person believed they were doing the right thing, and if so that their action was moral, but rather that, regardless of whether they believed it was right or not, the action subject to moral judgement was done intentionally.  If one believes truly that they do an action in moral good faith, but that is nonetheless an immoral action according to the *correct* code of morality, such a deontologist could dub them acting immorally, *even if the consequences were good!!*

Comment: That seems fair @PaulRoss. My answer was simplistic in this and other respects. I agree that under most deontological systems it is not about some kind of ethical good faith in which the actual rule matters less than a sincere intention but rather the agent's earnest attempt to follow the RIGHT ethical rules.

Answer (score 0):

A strict deontological perspective wouldn't care about intent or effect, but whether the actor acted in conformity to the rules that, *according to the deontological ethicist*, a person ought to follow.

Suppose we have Daisy the Deontological Ethicist and Max the Moral Agent.

Daisy has a rule that one should never cheat.

Daisy and Max agree that making games more fair is a good consequence.

Case 1: Max sincerely believes that since the other team has been cheating, the right thing to do is to cheat back, just to make the game fair. He cheats. The game becomes more fair. Daisy says Max has acted unethically despite his good intentions and good consequences.

Case 2: Max sincerely believes that since the other team has been cheating, the right thing to do is to cheat back, just to make the game fair. However, he is afraid of getting caught and shamed, so out of a cowardice, he does not cheat even though he thinks it is the right thing to do. The game remains unfair. Daisy says Max has acted ethically despite his bad intentions and bad consequences.

(Daisy might or might not also have a rule that says you should do what you think is right even if it involves small risks, in which case she might say that Max's decision to not take the risk was unethical even though his decision to not cheat was ethical.)

Answer (score -1):

There is a Buddhist sutta along the lines that

> there are four  kinds of deeds, the black deed with black  result
> (vipaka), the white deed with  white result, the black and white deed
> with black and white result, and the  neither black nor white deed
> with neither  black nor white result, it has no result  (Skt.
> a-vipaka). ...  The  fourth and last
> (which is, though this is  left implicit, neither harmful nor
> harmless, and therefore not deed at all  (it is the *Aufhebung* of
> deed), and  which will not lead to any re-arisal in  any world,
> harmful or harmless) is the  volition (cetana) to cut all three other
> kinds of deed, leading to the ending  of deed (kamma-kkhaya, Skt.
> karma-ksaya).  AN, II, 230-231 (4, 232)

[Kamma - A Study Guide](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/kamma.html#diversity)

The point is "Hell is paved with good intentions"; action in a complex world can yield undesired results.  The only way to stay clear is abandonment of deed, otherwise it's a gamble - and you should know that in advance, before you act.

Comment: This does not answer the question, unfortunately. OP asked specifically about deontological systems, not about the value of intention in general.

Comment: Fair doos. Will be interesting to see if a fangled deontological system comes to the same conclusion.